# POI API - Reference to font by the path

Tags: java, apache-poi

Am using POI API to generate excel reports and i have a font file

What i need is to use this font while generating the report, and while searching in the API functions , i didn't find any function that take the path of the font as a parameter.

only the following function supported:

```
createFont()
getFontAt(short idx)
findFont(short boldWeight,
            short color,
            short fontHeight,
            java.lang.String name,
            boolean italic,
            boolean strikeout,
            short typeOffset,
            byte underline)
```

Could you please advise, How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use HSSFFont for that. Take a look at the [API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html).

For example:

```
 public class ChangeCellFontName {  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

                /* Create Workbook and Worksheet */
                HSSFWorkbook my_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet my_sheet = my_workbook.createSheet("Cell Font");

                /* Get access to HSSFCellStyle */
                HSSFCellStyle my_style = my_workbook.createCellStyle();

                /* Create HSSFFont object from the workbook */
                HSSFFont my_font=my_workbook.createFont();

                /* Set the font name to Verdana */
                my_font.setFontName("Verdana");

                /* Also make the font color to RED */
                my_font.setColor(HSSFFont.COLOR_RED);

                /* attach the font to the style created earlier */
                my_style.setFont(my_font);

                /* Attach the new font to a cell */
                /* Create a row in the sheet */
                Row row = my_sheet.createRow(0);

                /* Create a cell */
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("The font for this text would be Verdana");

                /* Attach the style to the cell */
                cell.setCellStyle(my_style);


        }
}
```

This last example was taken from [here](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/Java-POI-XLS-XLSX-Change-Cell-Font-Name-Example.html). Also, another [example](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/set-font-style-in-excel-file-using-java.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Asier for you help :)

Comment: How can make this Font file included in the project without install it first , as i want whatever running this report into any environment  to be working even if the font not installed in this environment?

Comment: I'm not really sure if you can use fonts "out" of the HSSFFont nature... Sadly I can't help you with that : (. 

You could ask a new question regarding importing new fonts to the POI, anyway :)